# When I delete an opengl buffer then create a new one, the identifier increases

Tags: c, opengl

I created a opengl buffer using the variable id vbo. I then deleted the buffer and created a new one with a new variable id.

```c
unsigned int vbo;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo);

unsigned int vbo2;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo2);
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vbo2);
```

After deleting the first buffer, vbo2 is set to the value 2. I believe it is deleting the memory of the gpu as when I render to the screen using that buffer, it stops getting rendered after being deleted.

I just want clarification if I am missing something or that this isn't a problem.

I have tried dynamically allocating an array of unsigned int's using malloc then freeing it after deleting the buffer.

Then I use glGenBuffers again but the number of the variable identifier used in the function call still increases.

Comment: From https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glGenBuffers.xhtml _glGenBuffers returns n buffer object names in buffers. There is no guarantee that the names form a contiguous set of integers; however, it is guaranteed that none of the returned names was in use immediately before the call to glGenBuffers._ So, just because you deleted buffer 1, there is no guarantee that the object name will be reused. Or, contig. The first call could return 1, but the 2nd call could return 37 (e.g.). And, yes, IMO, if you delete the buffer, it frees up GPU memory and you can't use it.

Comment: Alright thanks for clarifying.